# Firebase messaging onResume, onLaunch or onBackgroundMessage are never called

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging package for flutter.
I want that whenever a user taps on the received notification, the flutter app opens and navigate to a particular screen depending on the  data sent by fcm.

But I am not able to achieve desired behaviour when either app is in the background or app is closed since onResume and onLaunch handler are never called. I have tried a number of solution like creating notification channel , using package like
flutter_local_notifications etc. But nothing worked for me.

Here is my FirebaseMessagingService class to handle fcm related tasks

```
class FirebaseMessagingService {
  final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();
  final RouterService _routerService = locator<RouterService>();
  final LocalStorageService _localStorage = locator<LocalStorageService>();
  Future initialise() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
    }
    _fcm.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          Map<String, dynamic> arguments = {};

          Map<String, dynamic> data = message['data'];
          if (data.containsKey('argument')) {
            if (data.containsKey('value')) {
              arguments[data['argument']] = data['value'];
            }
          }
          _routerService.navigationKey.currentState
              .pushReplacementNamed('${data['route']}', arguments: arguments);
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          Map<String, dynamic> arguments = {};
          Map<String, dynamic> data = message['data'];
          if (data.containsKey('argument')) {
            if (data.containsKey('value')) {
              arguments[data['argument']] = data['value'];
            }
          }
          _routerService.navigationKey.currentState
              .pushReplacementNamed('${data['route']}', arguments: arguments);
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          Map<String, dynamic> arguments = {};

          Map<String, dynamic> data = message['data'];
          if (data.containsKey('argument')) {
            if (data.containsKey('value')) {
              arguments[data['argument']] = data['value'];
            }
          }
          _routerService.navigationKey.currentState
              .pushReplacementNamed('${data['route']}', arguments: arguments);
        },
        onBackgroundMessage: _myBackgroundMessageHandler);
  }

  static Future<dynamic> _myBackgroundMessageHandler(
      Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    final RouterService _routerService = locator<RouterService>();
    if (message.containsKey('data')) {
      // Handle data message
      Map<String, dynamic> arguments = {};
      Map<String, dynamic> data = message['data'];
      if (data.containsKey('argument')) {
        if (data.containsKey('value')) {
          arguments[data['argument']] = data['value'];
        }
      }
      _routerService.navigationKey.currentState
          .pushReplacementNamed('${data['route']}', arguments: arguments);
    }

    if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
      // Handle notification message
      final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with the issue??

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for that. Firstly you have to add this code into your manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

When you have done that, you have to pass your firebase cloud messaging:

```
click_action => FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK
```

Then you can also pass as data for example `route => detailScreen`.

When you mave done that, you can call firebase messaging functions like `onResume` or `OnLaunch`, by checking that rout you passed in the FCM.

When you check the route you can navigate any screen with this function:

```
//PRIVATE METHOD TO HANDLE NAVIGATION TO SPECIFIC PAGE
void _navigateToSignalsPage(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  final MessageBean item = _itemForMessage(message);
  // Clear away dialogs
  //  Navigator.popUntil(context, (Route<dynamic> route) => route is PageRoute);
  if (!item.route.isCurrent) {
    print('heey girl ${item.route}');
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(selectedPage: 0,)));
  }
}
```